# NodeJS on External Host

Tags: javascript, host

I am using Nodejs with MySql. I want to host it on a host that supports apache, MySql etc,. I'm wondering - how will a node app fit in there? And what do I need to get it running on a free host?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a cloud service for your purpose since they usually provide a free tier where you can host you applications for free with some limitations. You can search on Internet something like "cloud provider Node.js" or "PaaS providers Node.js". A PaaS is a cloud solution which will permit you to deploy your Node.js app and bind it with a MySQL database. You can also use an IaaS for your purpose, but then you will need to install all the stuff and could be much more complex if you don't have experience.

This is an [example](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/NodeJS) about how to deploy an application on a PaaS. As you can see, it is really easy if you compare it with the standard way.